# Finding global minimizer and maximizer

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $f(x,y)=x^4-8x^2+y^4-18y^2$

Find the set of global minimizers of f?
Does f have a global maximizer?Justify?

I first calculated the gradient of f and then let partial derivative of x and y to be equal to 0.
Thereby the critical points I found are (0,0)(0,3)(0,-3)(6,0)(6,3)(6,-3).

I think a global maximizer doesn't exist as when limit of function goes to infinity from both x and y ,function goes to infinity.
But how to find if global minimizers are there?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=extrema+x%5E4-8x%5E2%2By%5E4-18y%5E2

Comment: You are quite welcome - a handy tool to verify your work! Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find the global minimizers without the use of the derivative: just note that 
$$
f(x,y)= x^4-8x^2+y^4-18y^2= (x^4-8x^2+16)+(y^4-18y^2+81)-97= (x^2-4)^2+(y^2-9)^2-97
$$
Then, for every $x,y \in\mathbb{R}$, we have that $f(x,y)\geq -97$ and at $x=\pm 2, y=\pm 3$, we have $f(x,y)=-97$

Comment: I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

The global minimizer has to be one of these
(0,0)(0,3)(0,-3)(6,0)(6,3)(6,-3). Check each to see which one makes $f$ the least value.
Because of symmetry, you can save some work.

But....

Are you sure of your answers?

$$
4 x^3 - 16x = 0 \Rightarrow x=0, \pm 2 \\
4 y^3 - 36 y=0 \Rightarrow y=0, \pm 3
$$
So you have 9 critica points: (0,0), (0,3), (0,-3), (2,0), (2,3), (2,-3), (-2,0), (-2,3), (-2,-3)

Comment: I have made a mistake.After computing the values of f at these critical points, do I have to check if these critical points are minimizers.What happens if the function value is lowest at a point which is actually a saddle point.Then I can't take that as a global minimizer right?

Comment: The minimum can **never** be at a saddle point. You can eliminate saddle points by looking at the second derivatives. I any case you will find, due to symmetry, multiple global minima (in fact any critical point with $x\ne 0$ and $y\ne0$.